# replace only relative paths in a markdown text string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have a markdown file loaded into a javascript string mdText.

The images and links that are relatively pathed need to be prefixed with a full url path. I was able to do this with this replace.

```
updatedMdText = mdText.replace(/\]\(/gi, '](' + urlRootPath);
```

The trouble is that some of the url's aren't relative `[Some Link Name](http://example.com)`

Is there a way to make it so the replace only happens on relative paths?

Comment: Could you provide an example relative path?

Comment: ![Image of something great](./some_image.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
updatedMdText = mdText.replace(/\]\((?!https?:\/\/)/gi, '](' + urlRootPath);
```

I have added negative lookahead for `http(s)://`, so lines where `](` is followed by `http(s)://` will not match.